# How do I clean a python dataframe? Name misspelling, pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe and I am trying to clean the typos where people enter the first and last names incorrectly.  How would I clean the dataset?  Can I use conditional statements to help?

```
Date           Last    First   City         Type
2016-01-01     smith   john    Riley Park   Staff
2016-01-02     smit    john    Riley Park   Staff
2016-01-03     smith   john    Riley Park   Staff
2016-01-04     smith   joh     Riley Park   Staff
2016-01-08     smith   john    Riley Park   Contractor
2016-01-04     smith   john    Fairview     Staff
2016-01-02     baker   bob     Strathcona   Staff
2016-01-03     bake    bob     Strathcona   Staff
2016-01-04     baker   bob     Strathcona   Staff
```

Desired cleaned dataset

```
Date           Last    First   City         Type
2016-01-01     smith   john    Riley Park   Staff
2016-01-02     smith   john    Riley Park   Staff
2016-01-03     smith   john    Riley Park   Staff
2016-01-04     smith   john    Riley Park   Staff
2016-01-08     smith   john    Riley Park   Contractor
2016-01-04     smith   john    Fairview     Staff
2016-01-02     baker   bob     Strathcona   Staff
2016-01-03     baker   bob     Strathcona   Staff
2016-01-04     baker   bob     Strathcona   Staff
```

I got really confused how I would clean this, I thought about creating other dataframes then merging it but I am hoping for some expert to help me with this.

EDIT: I want to have it only replace if the city and type staff are the same.

Comment: did you think about using np.where() or pd.where()

Comment: Try to create a list of ref, i suggest to use Levenshtein distance to check out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all typos just use the replace:

```
df.replace(['smit', 'joh', 'bake'], ['smith', 'john', 'baker'])
```

If you're sure there's always a correct value in the row above the typo, use replace with 'ffill' method:

```
df.replace(['joh', 'bake', 'smit'], method='ffill')
```

Replacement if only City and Type are the same:

```
df_gby = df.groupby(['City', 'Type'])

pd.concat( 
    [
        df_gby.get_group(group).replace(['joh', 'bake', 'smit'], method='ffill') 
             for group in df_gby.groups
    ]
)
```

Above, we grouped the df by City and Type, iteracting over each group and doing the replacement.

This way we are working on groups with the same values.

Comment: Can you add something to only replace the name where it only replaces the name if the city and type are the same?  what if you have a joh from Riley park and that is different from john at Fairview.

Comment: I updated my awnser

Answer (score 0):

```
from thefuzz import fuzz


def correct_typo(typo, ref_names, ratio=80):

    for name in ref_names :
        if fuzz.ratio(typo, name) > ratio :
            return name

    return typo
```

Comment: please see https://blog.paperspace.com/implementing-levenshtein-distance-word-autocomplete-autocorrect/

Comment: this is the closest method as all the other ones are just using a where statement.  can you help me implement?

Answer (score 0):

**You could use Where with condition of selection and change your value if not completed**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2016-01-01","2016-01-02","2016-01-03"],"Name['smith','smi',"Fathallah"],"LastName":["john","jon","Mohamed"]})


Date        Name        LastName
2016-01-01  smith       john
2016-01-02  smi          jon
2016-01-03  Fathallah   Mohamed


df["LastName"].where(lambda x:x[:2]=="jo","john",inplace=True)
df["Name"].where(lambda x:x[:2]=="sm","smith",inplace=True)

Date          Name        LastName
2016-01-01    smith         john
2016-01-02    smith         john
2016-01-03   Fathallah     Mohamed
```

Comment: I would have to go through every single name which is thousands of rows to do that lambda function.